# Is There Fingerprint Driver For Dell G7

Tags: drivers, security, 18.10, fingerprint-reader, lsusb

I Have Intentions To Switch To Ubuntu Full Time.I Tried Ubuntu In VM And It Could Not Detect The Fingerprint when i tried `lsusb` 
is this only in vm or is there drivers for goodfix fingerprint.

Edit: I tried fingerprint gui still not detected